# Alert box doesn't appear on matched/mismatched regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a regex to validate potential bitcoin addresses, now when I click the button for a quote I want the value entered in the form to get checked against the regex but it doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/arkqdc8a/5/

```js
var walletCheck = $('#wallet').val();
var reg = new RegExp("^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$");

$('#button1').on('click', function() {
 if (reg.test(walletCheck)) == false {
  alert("Inalid Address");
  }
   else {
    alert("Valid Address");
   }
 }
```

```html
<input type="form" 
       id="wallet" 
       maxlength="34" 
       pattern="^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$" 
    placeholder="Your Bitcoin wallet's address"></input><br><br>
<button id="button1">Click for a quote!</button>
```

Comment: `if (reg.test(walletCheck)) = false` this makes no sense at all. First the parenthesis are missmatched and `=` is an assignment not a comparison. It should be `==` or better `===`

Comment: When debugging code, check your console for errors first...

Comment: I tried with =, == & ===, and it didn't work. any other ideas?

Comment: I don't have an error consule, i'm coding on linux with geany.. =( what program would you suggest?

Comment: Use the console build in your browser, press F12 when in FF, Chrome or IE to open it

Comment: It should be `if (reg.test(walletCheck) == false) {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134713/discussion-between-nipboss-and-empiric).

Comment: THis is not even valid javascript, dear god

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You had some braces not closing properly and your equality check wasn't being done correctly either. Your fiddle didn't have jQuery imported as well.

```js
var reg = new RegExp("^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$");

$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    var walletCheck = $('#wallet').val();
    if (reg.test(walletCheck)) {
      alert("Valid address");
    } else {
      alert("Invalid address");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="wallet" maxlength="34" pattern="^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$" placeholder="Your Bitcoin wallet's address" />
<br>
<br>
<button id="button1">Click for a quote!</button>
```

Comment: Hi Rizja, so there's no need to check if the boolean is equal to true/false?

Comment: `reg.test(walletCheck)` is doing that check. It's the shorthand version of doing your equality check, the same as `reg.test(walletCheck) == true`.

Comment: @NipBoss `something == true` is either `true` or `false`. So why not just use `something` as the if condition. See what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

So you are missing a few things syntactically in your javascript code.

1. Your if condition needs to go in a bracket.
2. Use '==' or '===' for comparing the condition in if statement
3. In the last line, correct ')}' to be ')}'.

```js
  var walletCheck = $('#wallet').val();
  var reg = new RegExp("^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$");
  $('#button1').click(function() {
   if ((reg.test(walletCheck)) === false) {
    alert("Inalid Address");
    } else {
      alert("Valid Address");
     }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="form" id="wallet" 
       maxlength="34" 
       pattern="^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$" 
    placeholder="Your Bitcoin wallet's address"></input><br><br>
      <button id="button1">Click for a quote!</button>
```

Check this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0yOySBvZmpPfbzH88GyA?p=preview) for a working version of your code.